# How to change the Primary Key of a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I don't want to remove the Primary Key column and it's data. I just want to change it from column A to column B. What is the command syntax for that?

Comment: Do you mean to "rename"?

Comment: One line Solution, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ALTER TABLE Example DROP PRIMARY KEY;
 ALTER TABLE Example ADD PRIMARY KEY ('columnB');
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your SQL Server, the following URL has all the information you will need.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp